# SharedPreferences automatically get cleared when browser closed for flutter web

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-web, flutter-sharedpreference, flutter-web-browser

SharedPreferences is automatically cleared when browser is closed for flutter web.

There is no problem when flutter web is reloaded but the problem comes when closing the browser and again when relaunched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePrefrences works as expected in production mode, try

```
flutter build web
```

and serve files from the build/web directory (in your flutter project).